# Gradient has no stop info, when I upload vector asset in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-vectordrawable

I upload vector asset and it doesn't show, because I have issues "ERROR @ line 1: Gradient has no stop info", when I upload a vector image. This problem happens only with images which contains gradient. Here my xml of my vector image.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="512dp"
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="510"
    android:viewportHeight="510">
  <path
      android:pathData="m141.178,142.178c29.171,-29.417 69.569,-47.671 113.981,-47.628 40.946,0.04 78.304,15.413 106.638,40.693 4.06,3.622 10.576,3.384 14.423,-0.463l51.983,-51.983c4.233,-4.233 4.116,-11.15 -0.283,-15.21 -46.333,-42.767 -108.55,-68.574 -176.806,-67.558 -69.008,1.027 -131.43,29.692 -176.776,75.309 -5.056,5.086 0.858,66.659 0.858,66.659s37.519,28.885 65.982,0.181z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m141.178,142.178c29.171,-29.417 69.569,-47.671 113.981,-47.628 40.946,0.04 78.304,15.413 106.638,40.693 4.06,3.622 10.576,3.384 14.423,-0.463l29.831,-29.831c-2.598,-2.008 -5.16,-4.116 -7.66,-6.33 -38.891,-34.443 -89.49,-56.36 -145.66,-55.77 -58.254,0.612 -110.577,24.372 -148.41,62.47 -4.137,4.166 -5.762,36.744 -5.762,36.744s4.854,-0.439 42.619,0.115z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m94.56,253.55c-0.4,45.14 17.84,86.02 47.48,115.41l-22.75,49.095 -44.1,17.755c-46.36,-46.11 -75.09,-109.92 -75.19,-180.44 -0.1,-70.03 28.33,-133.76 74.34,-180.03l66.84,66.84c-28.46,28.7 -46.24,68.03 -46.62,111.37z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m94.56,253.55c-0.4,45.14 17.84,86.02 47.48,115.41l-36.55,36.56c-37.94,-37.68 -61.71,-89.61 -62.62,-147.09 -0.95,-59.79 22.62,-114 61.46,-153.1l36.85,36.85c-28.46,28.7 -46.24,68.03 -46.62,111.37z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m368.091,369.091c-29.238,28.971 -69.603,46.638 -114.129,46.356 -43.644,-0.276 -83.144,-17.983 -111.91,-46.498l-66.856,66.856c45.931,45.678 109.161,73.98 179.004,74.195 69.986,0.215 133.635,-28.565 179.94,-74.858l-19.108,-40.856z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m368.088,369.087c-29.24,28.972 -69.602,46.643 -114.127,46.363 -43.643,-0.276 -83.143,-17.983 -111.909,-46.501l-36.562,36.562c38.353,38.101 91.181,61.649 149.51,61.649 58.331,0 111.157,-23.549 149.511,-61.649z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m510,228.812c0,-5.027 -4.076,-9.103 -9.103,-9.103h-237.36c-4.503,0 -8.154,3.651 -8.154,8.154v78.481c0,4.503 3.651,8.154 8.154,8.154h115.921c11.94,0 19.354,13.03 13.213,23.269 -6.855,11.428 -15.1,21.901 -24.486,31.216 -0.035,0.036 -0.059,0.071 -0.095,0.107l66.06,66.06c3.119,-3.119 6.284,-6.24 9.474,-9.369 41.275,-45.774 66.376,-106.504 66.376,-172.755z">
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="m456.44,321.78c9.33,-28.2 -11.57,-57.28 -41.27,-57.28h-159.786v41.844c0,4.503 3.651,8.154 8.154,8.154h115.921c11.94,0 19.354,13.03 13.213,23.269 -6.833,11.391 -15.048,21.831 -24.396,31.124 -0.065,0.067 -0.117,0.131 -0.185,0.199l36.42,36.42c19.36,-19.21 35.02,-42.14 45.85,-67.62 2.229,-5.27 4.259,-10.64 6.079,-16.11z">
  </path>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your vector file is having some issues. so as a solution you can try below options:

1. Re-import your image and make sure to check the preview.
   I am attaching a screenshot of vector asset with some problem in it and highlighted it , have a look , also the preview is blank here as image is having some issue. so you have to check the same at your end.

[image]
 2. Ask your designer to look into it as may be he/she has added some components which are not supported by android studio yet.

Hope it helps.

Thank you!

Comment: When I open file as on your picture, I don't have preview and I have following error: "The image may be incomplete due encountered issues". And after opening issues I see "ERROR @ line 1: Gradient has no stop info"

Comment: then definitely this file is having some problem , contact to your designer to get it fixed.